# javascript on("load") in sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have this code in version sencha touch 1.1, how to make it works in Version 2?. "load" is not working

Html:

```
<img src="" id="previewImage"/>
```

Code:

```
this.domImage=Ext.get("previewImage");
this.domImage.on("load",function(){
    debugger; // not working
    a.sizePhotoInContainer();
    a.resizePhoto()
});
```

on() was deprecated: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.EventManager-method-on

Thanks!

Comment: @Jivings: domImage is: <img src="" id="previewImage" class="x-hidden-display"/>

Answer (score 1):

`load` is ***not a property*** for `image` component in ST2. It's an `event` that will be fired when image is loaded.

So, you need to `listen` for `load` event of `image` component in Sencha Touch 2.

Do it like this,

```
var img = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
    src: 'http://www.sencha.com/assets/images/sencha-avatar-64x64.png',
    height: 64,
    width: 64,
    listeners : {
        load : function {
          // ....
          // ....
          // ....
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Sencha, but I think it would be something like this...

```
// create image
var img = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
    src: 'http://www.sencha.com/example.png'
});
// callback on load
img.load = function() {
}
```

Or

```
var img = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
    src: 'http://www.sencha.com/example.png',
    load : function() {    }
});
```

Comment: img.load, it didn't work Sorry, I supposed I wrongly formulated the question, I did a change, please take a look again, Thanks!!!